# How can I create a both-sided chat box in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I create a both-sided chat message box, that will look like normal messenger, in PyQt?
As an example - my friend's msg should be on the left side and my msg should be on the right side of the chat box.

[Screenshoot as example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOBKH.png)

Comment: Tried to use QTextBrowser, but i cant print different member's msgs on different sides/

Comment: I recommend using QT creator and you can easily do this with qml

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [model/view framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html) -- [`QTableView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html) in particular.  Each row in the associated model has either column 0 populated for messages of others *or* column 1 populated for your own messages.

Comment: @G.M. thank u, but if i use table, chat ll split into 2 columns, short messages ll look nice, but long messages will not overlap each other and thats the problem.(

Comment: @MR.babady im actually using qml with QCustomWidgets library. But i cant understand how to create a both sided chat window ._.

Comment: add qml tag to your question

Comment: There is a QML tutorial that does what you're looking for [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/qmlsqlintegration/qmlsqlintegration.html)